# How to rescale Camera images in Flutter/Dart in Android?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-camera, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am doing object detection from tensorflow API in Android using model's tflite format. The model gives good results on validation set and gives nice boxes on any image from that dataset. But if I click the same dataset image shown on my PC's screen from my android camera the predictions are way worse. I think this is maybe due to the rescaling of the image. So I want to rescale the clicked image from the camera in android Dart / Flutter. The Camera Image is taken using the image_picker library in Flutter.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the format of image? CameraImage?

Comment: Yes, I have taken a camera image using image_picker API in flutter

Answer (score 0):

Flutter CamearPreview,  the image will be auto scaled base on device screen ratio, so the image will be stretched. try to use Transform widget to fit camera without scalling/stretching.

```
 CameraController _controller;    
 final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size; 
 final deviceRatio = size.width / size.height;

      Transform.scale(       
                      scale: _controller.value.aspectRatio / deviceRatio,
                      child: Center(
                        child: AspectRatio(
                          aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                          child: CameraPreview(_controller),
                        ),
                      ));
```